DEVISE localhost:3000/admins/sign_in link always redirects to localhost:3000 (rails 7)
I am building an app in Ruby on Rails 7 that has Admin and User side. after configuring Devise, all of my Devise routes redirect to "home#index". how can I fix this? I inititially thought it was because there were no Devise views in my /app/views but after running rails generate devise:views, and having the views created, the problem still persits. PLease assist
this is my routes.rb file and below that is my server logs
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Reveal health status on /up that returns 200 if the app boots with no exceptions, otherwise 500.
  # Can be used by load balancers and uptime monitors to verify that the app is live.
  get "up" => "rails/health#show", as: :rails_health_check

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
   root "home#index"

   authenticated :admin_user do
    root to: "admin#index", as: :admin_root
   end

   get "admin" => "admin#index"
end



=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.1.3.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 6.4.2 (ruby 3.3.1-p55) ("The Eagle of Durango")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 14050
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-06-01 07:34:29 +0200
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.5ms | Allocations: 286)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 339.3ms | Allocations: 78245)
Completed 200 OK in 360ms (Views: 347.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 82659)


Started GET "/admins/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-06-01 07:34:38 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Admin Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = ? ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 70ms (ActiveRecord: 7.4ms | Allocations: 17165)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-06-01 07:34:38 +0200
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 37)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 35.1ms | Allocations: 8276)
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 36.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 8535)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-06-01 07:35:12 +0200
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 159)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 65.8ms | Allocations: 25157)
Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 68.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 26088)


Started GET "/admin/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-06-01 07:35:20 +0200
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/admin/sign_in"):
  
Started GET "/admins/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-06-01 07:35:32 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Admin Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = ? ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 8.1ms | Allocations: 5881)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-06-01 07:35:32 +0200
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 37)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 32.8ms | Allocations: 8408)
Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 34.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 8662)


Started GET "/admins/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-06-01 07:44:14 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Admin Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = ? ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms | Allocations: 5332)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-06-01 07:44:14 +0200
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 3.5ms | Allocations: 157)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 570.5ms | Allocations: 26921)
Completed 200 OK in 585ms (Views: 580.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 27850)


you're already signed in, that's why you get redirected.

"I inititially thought it was because there were no Devise views in my /app/views". The Devise gem provides the views. There is no need to generate your own unless you want to customize the default views.

I modified my routes though, so that they could point to the admin. All the links from the "/admins" just take me back to "localhost:3000"    do you have any suggestions on how i can fix it @Alex

@Alex Because I set up "/views/admin/index.html.erb", wasn't it supposed to take me there after reload9ng the page?

All the links from the "/admins" just take me back to "localhost:3000" - after you sign in all devise routes take you to your root path or to the path you were trying to go to before signing in. also i think it should be authenticated :admin do

@Alex after restarting my machine, the admins/sign_in route does take me back to the sign in page but after logging in, it still takes me to home#index so do all the other devise routes. To create the user I did bin/rails c then Admin.create(email: "admin@example.com"  password: "password") and ctrl +dto log out of console. Was I supposed to do aAdmin.save? The problem persists even after using your recommendation toauthenticated :admin do`.

you also need to put authenticated :admin do above root "home#index".

I put it above root "home#index and it worked- took me straight to my "admin#index". Thank you @Alex. Lmao now after everything is working I run bin/dev and it returns /home/USER_NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin/foreman: 6: exec: /home/USER_NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin/ruby: not found. Any ideas on this

no sure, missing foreman? run gem install foreman which should happen automatically anyway. this should be a separate question.

@Alex thank you for your feedback it really was invaluable

In your logs you have:
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected

that means you're already signed in and you get redirected back to root path. You should also set up flash messages in your layout so you could see the notice devise gives you.
Second issue is your routes:
# this needs to come first to override home root when signed in
authenticated :admin do
  root to: "admin#index", as: :admin_root
end

root "home#index"

